# edit video with moviepy after downloading from youtube

Tags: python, urllib, moviepy, pytube

I'm trying to write a basic python script that downloads videos from youtube, clips 10 seconds of it, and then concats it with another pre-downloaded video I have in my root directory`whatever.mp4`.

I have a list of search words in `words.txt` that I loop over and download when I run my python script:

```
import urllib.request
import re
from pytube import YouTube
import os
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips

f = open('words.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    y = line.split()
    link = urllib.request.urlopen(f"https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={y}")
    pattern = r"watch\?v=(\S{11})"
    video_ids = re.findall(pattern, link.read().decode())
    vid = f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={video_ids[0]}"
    yt = YouTube(vid)
    yt.streams.filter(mime_type="video/mp4", progressive=True).first().download(output_path='highlights', filename=f"{y}.mp4")
    print("Video downloaded as mp4")

for filename in os.listdir("videos"):
    clip = VideoFileClip(filename).subclip(0, 10)
    rick = VideoFileClip('whatever.mp4')
    new = concatenate_videoclips([clip, whatever])
    new.write_videofile(f'new_{filename}.mp4')
f.close()
```

When I run the script the first video downloads successfully, but I get this error:

```
$ python3 index.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/Code/pytube_moviepy/index.py", line 23, in <module>
    clip = VideoFileClip(str(filename)).subclip(0, 10)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/VideoFileClip.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.reader = FFMPEG_VideoReader(filename, pix_fmt=pix_fmt,
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_reader.py", line 35, in __init__
    infos = ffmpeg_parse_infos(filename, print_infos, check_duration,
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_reader.py", line 270, in ffmpeg_parse_infos
    raise IOError(("MoviePy error: the file %s could not be found!\n"
OSError: MoviePy error: the file video1.mp4 could not be found!
Please check that you entered the correct path.
```

Everything else seems to be working which is why I'm confused:

1. The video is downloaded.
2. The video is saved as `video1.mp4` in the `videos` directory.
3. MoviePy can't find the file.

What's more confusing is that if my `whatever.mp4` file into the `videos` directory and then run the second half of my script (by commenting out the first for loop) the videos get concatenated. What am I doing wrong? What's the issue?

My file layout:

```
.
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── videos
│   └── video1.mp4
├── index.py
├── words.txt
└── whataver.mp4
```

Comment: In the first line of your for loop, did you mean to have `y = line.strip()` instead of `y=line.split()`?  line.split() is going to give you an list of single characters, which I would expect is messing up both your search and the filename generation.
The video is saved as `video1.mp4`, but at which ever step the error is occuring, it is looking for `video.mp4`.  Maybe generate the filename before calling yt.stream.filter() and store it in a variable so you can print it out as the program runs, instead of calculating `{y}.mp4` as part of the passed parameter.

Comment: when I run `y = line.split()` I get this:
`print(y)
['0', '1', '2']` (the numbers being the three parts of the line. That part works

Comment: Also I edited the error `video.mp4` is actually coming out as `video1.mp4` as in the error is saying the correct file could not be found. I just used stand in file names to make it easier.

Comment: Syntax highlighting should clearly tell you that there's a typo in the posted question. Please don't post code that doesn't run...

Comment: EDIT: fixed the typo code was missing a `"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow answer was pretty simple. Just had to add the directory in the second for loop:

```
for filename in os.listdir("videos"):
    clip = VideoFileClip(f"videos/{filename}").subclip(0, 10)
    rick = VideoFileClip('whatever.mp4')
    new = concatenate_videoclips([clip, whatever])
    new.write_videofile(f'new_{filename}.mp4')
```

I assumed that if I was looping through the directory that it would look for a file within that directory but I guess VideoFileClip needs the path from the root.